# SQL import via RODBC - wrong values after implicit? typecast

Tags: sql-server, r, import, type-conversion

I have a column in an SQL table which contains 15 digit IDs stored as nvarchar (255) in MSSQL (e.g. '30000005000008498').

If I run an sql query on this using the robdc library the data is implictly casted to numeric.

```
library("RODBC")

odbcChannel <- odbcConnect("TableName")

ID <- sqlQuery(odbcChannel, "SELECT DISTINCT [ID] FROM TEST4")
```

I have verified this via

```
str(ID)
```

Next thing I have tried is to cast the data to a character using

```
ID <- as.character(ID)
```

This works without getting an error message. Unfortunately, parts of the data is altered which is kind of bad for a unique ID:

Minimum Example:

```
a = 30000005000008498
b <- as.character(a)
```

output is:

```
[1] "30000005000008496"
```

I think it might have something to do with the maximum size of numeric. For smaller numbers, as.character works just fine. However, I could not figure out how to keep the initial ID when importing from SQL.

Question1: Is there any possibility to avoid the implicit typcast to num?

Question2: Any ideas how i can import the 15 digit character string from SQL without R changing it?

Comment: Would adding 'CAST ID AS CHAR` to your query help?

Comment: Try the `getSqlTypeInfo("Microsoft SQL Server" )` function in RODBC to view the data type mappings R is using. I'd also confirm the source data type with sqlColumns( odbcChannel, "TEST4").

Comment: Checked via sqlColumns, source data was fine. Nieke Aerts answer helped perfectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use as.is = TRUE.

```
testid <- sqlQuery(database,"SELECT CAST(id as CHAR) as id from my_table", as.is=TRUE);
```

Even if the column id numeric in the database, testid will be a data frame containing character inputs.
I think that as.is can be set for each column separately (using as.is = c(..)) or for all at the same time.

Probably the CAST(.. as CHAR) is not necessary when the column already is of type VARCHAR.

Comment: Worked perfectly, Explicit CAST (.. as CHAR) was not necessary. Thanks for your help!